# How to apply operation and sum over columns in R?

Tags: r

I want to apply some operations to the values in a number of columns, and then sum the results of each row across columns.  I can do this using:

```
x <- data.frame(sample=1:3, a=4:6, b=7:9)
x$a2 <- x$a^2
x$b2 <- x$b^2
x$result <- x$a2 + x$b2
```

but this will become arduous with many columns, and I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a simpler way.  Note that the dataframe contains other columns that I do not want to include in the calculation (in this example, column `sample` is not to be included).

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks CathG.  I just need to apply various functions (x^2 was just an example) to the columns and then sum the results.  I did know that I could enter the sum and function in a single command, but wanted to show the results to help illustrate what I meant.  Basically I am looking for a more efficient way to apply a given function to all values and then sum the results, without having to type it manually.  I'm thinking there must be a nice command for this?  Many thanks for your help

Comment: To apply a function to multiple columns of a data.frame you can use `lapply` like this: `x[] <- lapply(x, "^", 2)`. Note that I use `x[] <- ` in order to keep the structure of the object (data.frame). Afterwards, you could use `rowSums(df)` to calculat the sums by row efficiently

Comment: @Thomas, I posted an answer to generalize your request to any function, with 2 cases, according to the fact that the function can be vectorized or not (`f(c(a,b)) equal to c(f(a),f(b))`or not)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would simply subset the columns of interest and apply everything directly on the matrix using the `rowSums` function.

```
x <- data.frame(sample=1:3, a=4:6, b=7:9)

# put column indices and apply your function
x$result <- rowSums(x[,c(2,3)]^2)
```

This of course assumes your function is vectorized.  If not, you would need to use some `apply` variation (which you are seeing many of).  That said, you can still use `rowSums` if you find it useful like so.  Note, I use `sapply` which also returns a matrix.

```
# random custom function
myfun <- function(x){
    return(x^2 + 3)
}

rowSums(sapply(x[,c(2,3)], myfun))
```

Comment: Thanks cdeterman, this was a very simple command that worked well for me.  I was able to just use something like x$result <- rowSums(x[,c(2:70)]^2) to use this on a large number of columns (columns 2 to 70 in this case).  Thanks to you and everyone else for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **apply** function. And get those columns that you need with `c(i1,i2,..,etc)`.

```
apply(( x[ , c(2, 3) ])^2, 1 ,sum )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to convert the data set into the 'long' format, group it by `sample`, and then calculate the result. Here is the solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(x),id.vars = 'sample')[,sum(value^2),by=sample]
#   sample  V1
#1:      1  65
#2:      2  89
#3:      3 117
```

You can easily replace value^2 by any function you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a function named `somefunction` to some of the columns, whose indices or colnames are in the vector `col_indices`, and then sum the results, you can do :

```
# if somefunction can be vectorized :
x$results<-apply(x[,col_indices],1,function(x) sum(somefunction(x)))

# if not :
x$results<-apply(x[,col_indices],1,function(x) sum(sapply(x,somefunction)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to come at this one from a "no extensions" R POV.

It's important to remember what kind of data structure you are working with. Data frames are actually lists of vectors--each column is itself a vector. So you can you the handy-dandy lapply function to apply a function to the desired column in the list/data frame.

I'm going to define a function as the square as you have above, but of course this can be any function of any complexity (so long as it takes a vector as an input and *returns a vector of the same length*. If it doesn't, it won't fit into the original data.frame!

The steps below are extra pedantic to show each little bit, but obviously it can be compressed into one or two steps. Note that I only retain the sum of the squares of each column, given that you might want to save space in memory if you are working with lots and lots of data.

- create data; define the function
- grab the columns you want as a separate (temporary) data.frame
- apply the function to the data.frame/list you just created.
- lapply returns a list, so if you intend to retain it seperately make it a temporary data.frame. This is not necessary.
- calculate the sums of the rows of the temporary data.frame and append it as a new column in x.
- remove the temp data.table.

Code:

```
x <- data.frame(sample=1:3, a=4:6, b=7:9); square <- function(x) x^2 #step 1

x[2:3] #Step 2

temp <- data.frame(lapply(x[2:3], square)) #step 3 and step 4

x$squareRowSums <- rowSums(temp) #step 5

rm(temp) #step 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other apply solution

```
cols <- c("a", "b")
x <- data.frame(sample=1:3, a=4:6, b=7:9)
x$result <- apply(x[, cols], 1, function(x) sum(x^2))
```